# Display multiple WP pages on single WP page but in

Tags: wordpress

I'm using this code

```
   $args = array('post_type' => 'page', 'post__in' => array(208,7));
   query_posts($args);
```

To get multiple pages on single page.

The only problem that I have, it really does not matter if i put array(208,7) or
array(7,208) it is always last one displayed on top, so in my case I have 7,74,82,208, 
and I need them in order 74,208,7,82 but it is always 208, 82, 74, 7 ...

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`post__in` only tells which posts to fetch and does not define the order of them. If you want to set the order of pages try setting menu_order in wp menu and then

```
$args = array('post_type' => 'page', 
              'post__in' => array(208,7), 
              'orderby' => 'menu_order');
```

Of if you are already using menu_order for something else, you can use custom fields.

```
$args = array('post_type' => 'page', 
              'post__in' => array(208,7), 
              'orderby' => 'meta_value', 
              'meta_key' => 'custom_field_name');
```

Comment: Using "menu_order" (first example) works fine, but the second one does not, or "custom_field_name" should actually be some field name such as ID ?

Comment: I've just rechecked a bit. menu_order gives me chance to have them in order 7, 74, 82, 208 and without it 208, 82, 74, 7 but it does not resolve my issue that i need them in "order as mentioned in array members" :)